# In the given code what is the need of **kwargs when it runs without it(only with *args) also?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

```
def greet(fx):
  def mfx(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Good Morning")
    fx(*args, **kwargs)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    print("Thanks for using this function")
  return mfx
@greet
def add(a, b):
  print(a+b)
add(1, 2)
```

I tried using it with both arguments and with *args only but not able to find the use of **kwargs as the program runs without any problem with *args only.

Comment: Have you tried `add(a=1, b=2)` or `add(1, b=2)`?

Comment: The `**kwargs` parameter is useful for your decorator when the function you decorate has keyword parameters.

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` both can accept *zero* positional and keyword arguments, respectively. `add(a=1, b=2)` would work just as well. `add(c=3, d=4)` would fail, not immediately (since `add` takes arbitrary keyword arguments), but when `fx` is called (because the *original* `add` doesn't accept keyword arguments `c` or `d`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**args and kwargs are used when you don't know the quantity of arguments that are going to be given to a function.**

when using *args in a function any number of **positional arguments** can be excepted by it. It receives arguments as tuple.

when using **kwargs any number of **keyword arguments** can be excepted by it. It receives arguments as dict.**kwargs are useful when you want to access keyword arguments but you aren't 100% sure what they will be.

when you pass positional arguments to **kwargs error occurs and vice versa

And in your code you used `mfx(*args,**kwargs)` and you gave it `1,2`*(positional arguments)* and they all were passed to args not kwargs. if you want to give arguments to kwargs then use (a=1,b=2) if you do this the arguments will be passed to kwargs.

if you want to know diff between **keyword and positional arguments** [link here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keyword-and-positional-argument-in-python/)

if you want to know **more about args and kwargs** [link here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)